# Printing blade directive from database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to return blade directives inside another directive (data stored in database)

## Example + Code

`{{$category->title}}` shows category title but it also stored in another table in database like `category {{$category->title}} has 45 posts and etc.` (some additional texts) then I get this in my blade:

`{!!$myCustom!!}` so this `myCustom` has to print something like:

```
category LARAVEL has 45 posts and etc.
```

but what I get currently is:

```
category {{$category->title}} has 45 posts and etc.
```

**The title part won't print**.

Any idea?

Comment: What's inside $myCustom variable? Please add a bit of more code.

Comment: @KamalPaliwalthis is basically all the code that i have and inside mycustom is  this `category {{$category->title}} has 45 posts and etc.`

Comment: Why you need to use it like this {{ category {{$category->title}} has 45 posts and etc. }}. Instead you can direcly use it like {{ "category " . $category->title . " has 45 posts and etc." }}

Comment: @KamalPaliwal this is seo template same as what i try to achieve has made for magento here it is https://www.mageworx.com/magento-seo-meta-templates-extension.html so you can see why i'm trying to do this and how it works

Comment: I've tried this already `Instead you can direcly use it like {{ "category " . $category->title . " has 45 posts and etc." }}` doesn't work

Comment: What error you are getting in this?

Comment: no error it simply print it as it is `category $category->title has 45...`

Comment: If you are using $category->title only then also it won't print your category title?

Comment: will print.....

Comment: @KamalPaliwal no idea?

Comment: It seems a bit strange. You can print it by breaking it into multiple parts like {{ "Category" }} {{ $category->title }} {{ " has 45 posts and etc." }}. Though its not good one but might help you to perform your work

Comment: how to do that?